# JS how to return the dogs that match a select breed?

Tags: javascript, loops, object, for-loop

I am new to coding and cannot workout why my code is not working. Dose anyone have any suggestion of how to fix it?

The question I have been given is this;

```
This function takes an array of dog objects and returns an array of the names of all the pugs.
E.g. [
  {name: 'Beatrice', breed: 'Lurcher'},
  {name: 'Max', breed: 'Pug'},
  {name: 'Poppy', breed: 'Pug'}
]
will return ['Max', 'Poppy']
```

This is the code I have written;

```
function getPugNames(dogs) {    
    let pugs = []
    let reg = /(pug)/g
    for (let i = 0; i < dogs.length; i ++) {
        if(reg.test(dogs[i].bread)) {
            pugs.push[i].name
        }
    } return pugs
}
```

My code will be run against this;

```
describe("getPugNames", () => {
    it("returns [] when passed []", () => {
        expect(getPugNames([])).to.eql([]);
    });

    it("returns an array of pug names when passed an array of dog objects", () => {
        const dogs = [
            { name: "Beatrice", breed: "Lurcher" },
            { name: "Max", breed: "Pug" },
            { name: "Poppy", breed: "Pug" }
        ];
        expect(getPugNames(dogs)).to.eql(["Max", "Poppy"]);
        const dogs2 = [
            { name: "Steven", breed: "Lurcher" },
            { name: "Daphne", breed: "Pug" },
            { name: "Sandy", breed: "Labrador" },
            { name: "Mike", breed: "Pug" },
            { name: "Spike", breed: "Pug" }
        ];
        expect(getPugNames(dogs2)).to.eql(["Daphne", "Mike", "Spike"]);
        const dogs3 = [
            { name: "Kevin", breed: "Labrador" },
            { name: "Patch", breed: "Rottweiler" },
            { name: "Miles", breed: "Lurcher" },
            { name: "Sandy", breed: "Pug" },
            { name: "Spot", breed: "Pug" },
            { name: "Josephine", breed: "Terrier" },
            { name: "Eric", breed: "Pug" }
        ];
        expect(getPugNames(dogs3)).to.eql(["Sandy", "Spot", "Eric"]);
    });
});
```

This is the error that I am being given;

[image]

Comment: Well other than the typo where "breed" is spelled "bread", what is the problem?

Comment: Your regex is case sensitive, if you want case insensitive matching then replace it with `let reg = /pug/gi`. Otherwise replace it with `let reg = /Pug/g`. Also you probably don't need `Regex` for that, you're testing exact match (`===`)

Comment: Welcome to SO. If one of the answers was useful, please accept/upvote. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You just made some array of names, you need names of pugs, you can use filter  your array like pugs.filter(p => p.breed === ‘pug’) this will give you an array with pug only elements(check filter documentation), than just take name from it using map, map transforms your array according to given callback function that accept array element and must return new element(check array.map)

Answer (score 0):

`pugs.push[i].name` is a mistake. You should have `pugs.push(dogs[i].name);`.

Also, you don't really need a regex for `pug`. Just check like this:

`if (dogs[i].breed.toLowerCase() === "pug")`

Answer (score 0):

You regular expression is `/(pug)/g` where it should be `/(Pug)/g`. But in my opinion if don't even need to use Regex. When it's direct comparison between strings you can use the comparison operator `==` or `===`.
Other issue in your code it's how you are pushing to the array. Should be `pugs.push(dogs[i].name)`and not `pugs.push[i].name`. Therefore this is my suggestion:

```
function getPugNames(dogs) {

  let pugs = []
  for (let i = 0; i < dogs.length; i ++) {
    if(dogs[i].bread === 'Pug') {
      pugs.push(dogs[i].bread)
    }
  } 

  return pugs
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I corrected your version and created an easier version for you. Here it goes:

```js
//corrected version
function getPugNames(dogs) {    
    var pugs = [];
    var reg = /pug/gi
    for (let i = 0; i < dogs.length; i ++) {
        reg.lastIndex = 0;
        if (reg.test(dogs[i].breed)) 
            pugs.push(dogs[i].name);
    };
    return pugs
}

//easier version:
var getPugNames2 = dogs=>dogs
    .map(d=>d.breed.toLowerCase() == "pug" ? d.name : null)                    
    .filter(e=>e);

const dogs1 = [
    { name: "Beatrice", breed: "Lurcher" },
    { name: "Max", breed: "Pug" },
    { name: "Poppy", breed: "Pug" }
];
const dogs2 = [
    { name: "Steven", breed: "Lurcher" },
    { name: "Daphne", breed: "Pug" },
    { name: "Sandy", breed: "Labrador" },
    { name: "Mike", breed: "Pug" },
    { name: "Spike", breed: "Pug" }
];
const dogs3 = [
    { name: "Kevin", breed: "Labrador" },
    { name: "Patch", breed: "Rottweiler" },
    { name: "Miles", breed: "Lurcher" },
    { name: "Sandy", breed: "Pug" },
    { name: "Spot", breed: "Pug" },
    { name: "Josephine", breed: "Terrier" },
    { name: "Eric", breed: "Pug" }
];

console.log(getPugNames([]));
console.log(getPugNames(dogs1));
console.log(getPugNames(dogs2));
console.log(getPugNames(dogs3));
console.log(getPugNames2([]));
console.log(getPugNames2(dogs1));
console.log(getPugNames2(dogs2));
console.log(getPugNames2(dogs3));
```

You had some errors.

- First you have a typo on breed. You wrote 'bread' instead.
- you have to set `reg.lastIndex = 0` because regex, called several times may return different results
- you had a syntax error on push,
- regex must be case insensitive

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Within the code you wrote:

```
function getPugNames(dogs) {    
    let pugs = []
    let reg = /(pug)/g
    for (let i = 0; i < dogs.length; i ++) {
        if(reg.test(dogs[i].bread)) {
            pugs.push[i].name
        }
    } return pugs
}
```

You had some typos and errors. First off, you don't *really* need a regular  expression to check the dog breed - see my `if` statement:

```
if (dogs[i].breed == "Pug") {...}
```

(You also had a typo - you spelled `breed` with an a, like `bread`.)

Secondly, your syntax for [`Array.prototype.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) is wrong - it should be this:

```
pugs.push(dogs[i].name);
```

So after you've done all that, your code should look like this:

```
function getPugNames(dogs) {
    let pugs = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < dogs.length; i++) {
        if (dogs[i].breed == "Pug") {
            pugs.push(dogs[i].name);
        }
    }
    return pugs;
}
```

---

However, if you really wanted to make the code smaller and faster, you could use [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [ES6 arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) like so:

```
const getPugNames = (dogs) => dogs.filter(d => if (d.breed == "Pug") return d.name);
```